# If set_fact is scoped to a host, can I use 'dummy' host as a global variable map?

Tags: ansible

I have defined two group of hosts: `wmaster` and `wnodes`. Each group runs in its play:

```
- hosts: wmaster
  roles:
    - all
    - swarm-mode
  vars:
    - swarm_master: true

- hosts: wnodes
  roles:
    - all
    - swarm-mode
```

I use host variables (`swarm_master`) to define different behavior of some role.

Now, my first playbook performs some initialization and I need to share data with the nodes. What I did is to use `set_fact` in first play, and then to lookup in the second play:

```
- set_fact:
    docker_worker_token: "{{ hostvars[smarm_master_ip].foo }}"
```

I don't like using the `swarm_master_ip`. How about to add a dummy host: `global` with e.g. address `1.1.1.1` that does not get any role, and serves just for holding the global facts/variables?

Comment: You can use `hostvars[groups['wmaster'][0]]` syntax instead of `swarm_master_ip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How about to add a dummy host: global

I have actually found this suggestion to be quite useful in certain circumstances.

```
---
- hosts: my_server

  tasks:

      # create server_fact somehow

    - add_host:
        name: global
        my_server_fact: "{{ server_fact }}"

- hosts: host_group

  tasks:
    - debug: var=hostvars['global']['my_server_fact']
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Ansible 2 then you can take use of [`delegate_facts`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#delegated-facts) during your first play:

```
- name: set fact on swarm nodes
  set_fact: docker_worker_token="{{ some_var }}"
  delegate_to: "{{ item }}"
  delegate_facts: True
  with_items: "{{ groups['wnodes'] }}"
```

This should delegate the `set_fact` task to every host in the `wnodes` group and will also delegate the resulting fact to those hosts as well instead of setting the fact on the inventory host currently being targeted by the first play.

Comment: TIL. Thanks for posting this, works a treat! And if you want to delegate the fact to _all_ hosts, use `with_items: "{{ groups['all'] }}"`